# How to Deativate parent element click event if child anchor tag is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a situation in which I am creating dynamic content from my database. In which I am creating `<div>` with content in it. And I have added `onclick` event that `<div>`. If user click on the content of the div which means on `<div>` it opens a popup window. But if there is a anchor tag in the content. At that time if user clicks on anchor tag, Both the event executes it also opens the link page and popup.

I want to prevent that div `onclick` when anchor tag is clicked.

Is there any this that can help me?

Comment: Since your generating content serverside, or at least thats what is sounds like. Your best bet may be to add the onclick handler as an attribute.  `onclick="return false;"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use jQuery, try **stopPropagation()** function like this :

simple example :

```
$("div a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // your code here...
});
```

---

Or enhanced example with classes and IDs :

html :

```
<div id="content">
    ...
    <a href="/your/uri/here" class="noPropagation">my link</a>
    ...
</div>
```

js:

```
$("div#content a.noPropagation").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // your code here...
});
```

---

here is documentation : https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're adding the `<div>` dynamically, you can bind a click event handler to the closest ancestor to the dynamic content.  Here's one way to do it:

```
$('.some-container').on('click', 'div.dynamic-content a', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/7c51j7av/

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    click me
    </div>
 </div>  



$(".outer").click(function(){
        alert("Here");
    });

    $(".inner").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("Stopped it");
    });
```